# "That's the exactly reason why ..." vs "That's the exact reason why ..."

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs, emphasis

exact vs exactly

Which expression is right? Or Both of them?

And why?

---

"That's the very reason" is another expression with the same meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either say, "That's exactly why" or "For that exact reason".

"That's the exactly reason why" is incorrect way of expressing because it doesn't make any sense in English language.

"For this/that very reason" is pretty much similar to which we have discussed above.

Comment: "That's exactly the reason why" is also used.